# sequelize no permite guardar cantidades muy grandes "99999.99", les cambia el valor sqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, sequelize.js

Trato de realizar un registro con una cantidad de un millon de pesos y al momento de que sequelize hace el insertado en la base de dato me aguarda un valor diferente al que envie y mas pequeño, pense que era error mio, pero envio esta cantidad y si me la aguarda correcta **14546.33** y cualquiera que sea menor, pero envio esta **19999.99** y en bd me aparece lo siguiente **1553.25** pero sequelize me retorna lo siguiente

````
   "datos": [
       {
           "id": 5,
           "Nombre": "Prueba 5",
           "TPresupuesto": 19999.99,
           "createdAt": "2020-07-07T16:37:50.655Z",
           "updatedAt": "2020-07-07T16:37:50.655Z"
       }
   ],
   "mensaje": "Operación generada con éxito." ```
como si todo lo viera realizado bien
````

Comment: que tal si nos dice el tipo de dato que tiene `TPresupuesto ` probablemente tengas que hacer un cambio a nivel de tabla

Comment: es decimal(12,2), como un cambio de nivel?  @JackNavaRow

Comment: creo que debes ampliar ese campo a  que tal un tipo money

Comment: Ya trate de ponerlo money, double, numeric, etc y con ningún tipo de dato se aguarda la cantidad correcta @JackNavaRow pense que era sql pero hago la query que arroga sequelize y si inserta bien la información ...

Comment: intenta agregar el valor via sqlserver si no te da error creo que el error es sequelize

Comment: si es sequelize , porque si agrego el valor directo a sqlserver todo funciona bien.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de `Sequelize` estás usando? Hay un [problema](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/12086) con versiones anteriores a la `5.21.12`. Me parece que tu problema encaja allí. Saludos